# onclick not updating.Showing the old value even after using .onclick="hideList()";

Tags: javascript, onclick

The value of onclick is not getting replaced. The console window is showing it as unchanged.
Here is the javascript code:

```
function viewList(){
  var c=document.querySelector(".list");
  c.style.display= "block";
  document.querySelector(".box").style.height="700px";
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick="hideList()";
  console.log(document.getElementById("btn"));
}
function val(p){
  var i=document.getElementsByClassName("valued");
  var j=document.createAttribute("value");
  j.value=p.textContent;
  i[0].setAttributeNode(j);
}       
function hideList(){
  var c=document.querySelector(".list");
  c.style.display= "none";
  document.querySelector(".box").style.height="500px";
}
```

Comment: please add your HTML

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You should also use `.onclick = hideList;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//if you want to set string at function use this way
document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute('onclick',"hideList()");
//if you want set function variable then 
document.getElementById("btn").onclick=hideList;
```

Update:

```
//This will set the method to a string
document.getElementById("btn").onclick="hideList()";
```

Comment: thank you.It worked.But can you please tell document.getElementById("btn").onclick="hideList()"; didnt worked.Its a function afterall so should braces be necessary?

Comment: the reason now in the main post

Comment: Sorry didnt quite get it.What do you mean by set the method to a string?

Comment: actually this "hideList()" doesnot refers to the function hideList. Its just simple combination of letters(string)